# Warning curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Tags: php, json, curl

I keep getting this curl error

> Warning curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given
>
> curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /var/www/mbl.domain.com/html/admin/functions/api/jobs_send.php at 706

Code:

```
$request = urlencode($xml);
$url    = 'http://integrated.com/1.3';
$query  = 'token=' . $token . '&';
$query .= 'idomain=' . $idomain . '&';
$query .= 'cdomain=' . $cdomain . '&';
$query .= 'request=' . $request;
if(!$ch = curl_init()){
    die("Could not init cURL session.\n");
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip"); // we are making our api call fast by 70%
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sizeof($query));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xmlObj  = simplexml_load_string($result,"SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

line 706:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, sizeof($query));
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such option as `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` in PHP. That is automatically set for you internally when you specify `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

You are getting the error you are because PHP sees the undefined constant `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`, turns it into a string (`"CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE"`), and passes that into the function. This causes the error, because all the `CURLOPT_*` constants are actually integers. (The undefined constant to string conversion will raise a warning; if you are logging warnings/errors, it should show up in your logs.)

Also: not causing your problem, but an error nonetheless: `sizeof($string) === 1`. `sizeof` is an alias for `count`, which returns `1` for scalars. For a string's length, you want to use `strlen($string)` instead.

Comment: @Coci The *same* error? Which line is it complaining about, then, after you remove the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE` line?

Comment: when i remove this line it gives me require_once(/var/www/mbl.domain.com/html/admin/functions/api/jobs_send.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Does that file exist? That code isn't even in your original question.